# Windows computer can not connect to my network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My question is why my 2 Linux Xubuntu laptops my NAT and all the android phones work fine with my wireless router, but Windows laptops and iPhones can not connect to the router? They can connect to the wireless modem Though.

[image]

Comment: I checked the data log from my router and it says: "connection completed" and "authentication succeeded" for the windows laptops. Also the DHCP server reserves a IP-adres for my windows laptops but the laptops wont use those. I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have two LANs, one numbered 192.168.10.0/24 provided by your wireless modem and one numbered 192.168.0.0/24 provided by your wireless router. Devices on the wireless modem's LAN are considered "outside" the wireless router's LAN since they're on its Internet side.

I would strongly suggest changing your setup so you only have one LAN. The wireless router's Internet port is supposed to be used for a connection to the Internet, not for a connection to a LAN.